# Any way to make CSS flex flow downward while having multiple columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, multiple-columns

I have the following flex component:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px 32px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
flex-basis: calc(33% - 32px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Toni and Dwight Beavers</li>
    <li>Debra Coleman</li>
    <li>Ashley Dwight</li>
    <li>Paul and Madeline Green</li>
    <li>Jon and Allison Kelly</li>
    <li>Samar and William Longjohnson</li>
    <li>J. May Liang and James Linament</li>
    <li>Timothy R. Landry</li>
    <li>Carrie and David Mason</li>
    <li>Luke Frazier and Robert Peters</li>
    <li>Mei Xu and Allessandro Reiner</li>
    <li>Jennifer and Jimmy Revesi</li>
    <li>Cinthia and Horacio Rozalyn</li>
    <li>Margarita Arroyave-Wessel and David Wemmer, MD</li>
    <li>Angela and Kyle Westberger</li>
    <li>Linda D. Rabbitt and John Wheaton</li>
    <li>Kathie and Mike Wiener</li>
    <li>Rochdi Young</li>
</ul>
```

It *looks* the way it should but it flows left to right, and the client wants it to flow down, so that it's alphabetized downward per column.

I tried to do this with column:3.

```css
ul {
columns: 3
}

li {
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-right: 32px
}
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>Toni and Dwight Beavers</li>
        <li>Debra Coleman</li>
        <li>Ashley Dwight</li>
        <li>Paul and Madeline Green</li>
        <li>Jon and Allison Kelly</li>
        <li>Samar and William Longjohnson</li>
        <li>J. May Liang and James Linament</li>
        <li>Timothy R. Landry</li>
        <li>Carrie and David Mason</li>
        <li>Luke Frazier and Robert Peters</li>
        <li>Mei Xu and Allessandro Reiner</li>
        <li>Jennifer and Jimmy Revesi</li>
        <li>Cinthia and Horacio Rozalyn</li>
        <li>Margarita Arroyave-Wessel and David Wemmer, MD</li>
        <li>Angela and Kyle Westberger</li>
        <li>Linda D. Rabbitt and John Wheaton</li>
        <li>Kathie and Mike Wiener</li>
        <li>Rochdi Young</li>
    </ul>
```

This sorts them in the right order, but there are no longer defined rows, and the elements are not aligned horizontally as they were with flex.

Is there any way to get both? Whether with flex, column, or grid, I just want to have it look the same as it does with flex (aligned rows, all elements are balanced in a grid-like appearance) but flow down the columns instead of across. Like the picture below, which I manually achieved by hardcoding a height onto each li element

[image]

Comment: To wrap you need to limit the height of the flex container

Comment: So it's not possible if the content is dynamic and it does not have a fixed height?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of items?

Comment: No, the entire thing is dynamic

Comment: There isn't a pure css way to solve that as far as I know

Comment: Nope, the container needs to know when to wrap so there must be a limit somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can manage that with a defined number of rows.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

li {
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Toni and Dwight Beavers</li>
  <li>Debra Coleman</li>
  <li>Ashley Dwight</li>
  <li>Paul and Madeline Green</li>
  <li>Jon and Allison Kelly</li>
  <li>Samar and William Longjohnson</li>
  <li>J. May Liang and James Linament</li>
  <li>Timothy R. Landry</li>
  <li>Carrie and David Mason</li>
  <li>Luke Frazier and Robert Peters</li>
  <li>Mei Xu and Allessandro Reiner</li>
  <li>Jennifer and Jimmy Revesi</li>
  <li>Cinthia and Horacio Rozalyn</li>
  <li>Margarita Arroyave-Wessel and David Wemmer, MD</li>
  <li>Angela and Kyle Westberger</li>
  <li>Linda D. Rabbitt and John Wheaton</li>
  <li>Kathie and Mike Wiener</li>
  <li>Rochdi Young</li>
</ul>
```